# Windows 8.1 BAD_HEADER_POOL BSOD

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod

I run Windows 8.1 on my PC and my work laptop. Yesterday I had 2 bluescreens on my laptop (never had them before on that machine) and today I had like 5 bluescreens on my PC.

All the bluescreens on the PC and 1/2 on the laptop were BAD_POOL_HEADER errors.
They happened in completely random moments: browsing the web, watching movies, using Hyper-V.

The things that are in common between the 2 computers:

- the same OS - Windows 8.1 x64
- up to date system (maybe its something about Patch Tuesday updates?)
- they both run Hyper-V
- there are some common applications like Opera, SQL Server and a few others (most of the applications are different on both computers)

I looked through logs and they say that there was a reboot after error checking and the information was dumped to C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP 
I can't see such a file even though I turned off hiding hidden files and hiding protected OS files.

Comment: Have you browsed Windows folder as administrator? Could you check whether there are some dumps in C:\Windows\Minidump ?

Comment: I always use the admin account. I didn't find any methods or browsing folders as administrator. There are a few files in Minidump but I cant read any valuable information from them.

Comment: Were some of those minidumps created at time of BSODs? Could you upload them somewhere? Or at least post output from Windbg (ideally with symbols configured).

Comment: Yes, they are from the times of bluescreens. I'll upload them in a minute.

Comment: http://1drv.ms/1EeNygL - here are the dmp files from the Minidump folder

Comment: The crash happened because `vmswitch!RndisDevHostCleanupMessageOpContext` function freed invalid memory. Vmswitch.sys is part of Hyper-V (Network Virtualization Service Provider). So there may be a bug in it. It's really hard to tell anything more (at least w/o full dump). Try to search Google for vmswitch+BSOD combination, maybe you'll find something that will help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21941/discussion-between-ge0rdi-and-lukasz-kastelik).

Comment: active driver verifier (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and share new dumps. Maybe some other driver corrupted the memory that the Hyper-V driver now uses.